# Firebase cloud functions script not running

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have two objects in my firebase database:

Locale:

```
"39A81620-80EB-411B-80E2-C482824B7EF5" : {
      "Abilitato" : true,
      "Cap" : "00193",
      "Città" : "Roma",
      "ColoreFont" : "Bianco",
      "ColorePagina" : "Nero",
      "Descrizione" : "",
      "EmailLocale" : "test@gmail.com",
      "Font" : "Deco Future Black",
      "ImmagineCopertina" : "test_image",
      "Indirizzo" : "Via Dei Cosmati 3",
      "Latitudine" : 41.9053562,
      "Longitudine" : 12.4732003,
      "Nascosto" : false,
      "Nome" : "GUS",
      "PaginaFacebook" :"",
      "Proprietario" : "Eoh5yGzaPxWtZRiq7HAZL5WRu592",
      "Regione" : "Lazio",
      "SitoWeb" : "",
      "Telefono" : "06 8692 9033"
    }
```

and Utente:

```
"DDyGMUkbWjf8ucEQxNaxvI1wWPS2" : {
      "Cellulare" : "3300000000",
      "Citta" : "Roma",
      "Cognome" : "Zollo",
      "Compleanno" : 864597600,
      "ConversioniRimaste" : 2,
      "FBLiked" : false,
      "FBShared" : false,
      "ImmagineProfilo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hangover-e0428.appspot.com/o/Utenti%2FDDyGMUkbWjf8ucEQxNaxvI1wWPS2%2FFoto%2FImmagineProfilo%2FImmagineProfilo.jpg?alt=media&token=5e31ef8f-7ab5-4bee-aa48-8ee0687a23f1",
      "LikeTotali" : 0,
      "Nome" : "Davide",
      "NuoviLike" : 0,
      "Privacy" : false,
      "PuntiHangover" : 0,
      "Regione" : "Lazio",
      "Sesso" : "Maschio",
      "isPR" : false,
      "token" : "eiL9ca2vXw8:APA91bFK4LHawfdqm_z0Ok0gRl-wHGaVhVjqNhjUXQtIJDqwqEAOKbJRUG1q8DkoviCBV1k4rYLlqmlCXaWiZQDBemJKH4rTb9sACawLs8D_7GE_TexmwHspYc8GsWxRAkPrjT3NbsUN"
    }
```

Whenever a Locale change from hidden to visible the "Nascosto" attributes change from true to false , i want to notify the users that the Locale is so open so I have this cloud function:

```
//Rileva quando un locale passa da nascosto a visisbile e manda una notifica a tutti gli utenti della regione
exports.riAperturaLocale = functions.database.ref("Locali/{IDLocale}/Nascosto").onWrite(event =>{

    let stato_apertura = event.data.toJSON(); // valore di apertura o chiusura
    let ID_Locale = event.params.IDLocale;
    let nascosto = Boolean(stato_apertura);

    if(!nascosto) // il locale sta aprendo
    {
        console.log("Il Locale sta aprendo...")
        let locale = admin.database().ref("Locali").child(ID_Locale).once('value');
        return locale.then(snap =>{

            let dati_locale = snap.val();
            let regione = dati_locale["Regione"];

            ottieniUtentiRegioneLocale(dati_locale,regione);
        })

    }else{
        console.log("Il Locale sta chiudendo...:");
    }

    return 0;

})

//Ottiene un elenco di utenti nella regione del locale passato come parametro
function ottieniUtentiRegioneLocale(Locale,RegioneLocale){

    console.log("Notifico utenti per apertura locale...");

    let tutti_utenti = admin.database().ref("Utenti").once('value');
    return tutti_utenti.then(snap =>{

        console.log("Leggo utenti");
        var da_notificare = []// contiene gli Utenti da notificare

        snap.forEach((child) => {

            console.log("confronto utenti...");

            let IDUtente = String(child.key); // ID dell'Utente corrente
            let ValoriUtente = child.toJSON(); //Valori dell'utente che si sta scansionando

            let regione_user = ValoriUtente["Regione"];

            if(regione_user == RegioneLocale){
                da_notificare.push(IDUtente);
            }
        })

        if(da_notificare.length != 0){

            da_notificare.forEach((user) => {

                let img = Locale["ImmagineCopertina"];
                // creo la notifica 
                let testo = Locale["Nome"] + " " + "di" + " " + Locale["Città"] + " ha aperto, " 
                + "entra a scoprire tutti gli Eventi!"; 

                notificaUtente(user,"Un nuovo Locale ha aperto!",testo,img,"notifica");

            })

        }else{
            console.log("Non ci sono utenti da notificare...");
        }

    })

}

//Invia una notifica all'Utente passato come parametro
function notificaUtente(IDUtente,titolo,testo,URL,tipo){

    console.log("mando notifica a: " + IDUtente);

    let TokenDispositivo = admin.database().ref("Utenti").child(IDUtente).child("token").once('value');
    return TokenDispositivo.then(snap =>{

        let token = String(snap.val());

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
             notification: {
                title: titolo,
                body: testo,
                sound: 'default',
                badge:"1"
            },
            data:{"tipo":tipo,
                    "url":URL,
                "testo":testo,
                "titolo":titolo,
            "mittente":IDUtente}
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
            const error = response.error;
            if (error){
                console.log("Errore notifica" + error);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Note that notificaUtente() works fine for the other functions; whenever those functions are invoked they should scan for all the users that have the "Regione" attribute same as "Regione" of the Locale but when the code is executed it wont run pass the " console.log("Leggo utenti");" line of code, here is the firebase console output:

[Firebase console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0WWE.png)

[image]

why? I'm new to node.js and i need little help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you refactor your Cloud Function as follows. You don't need to:

a/ Do event.data.toJSON(). The data is already available as a    JavaScript object with `event.data.val()`

b/ Look at the "Nascosto" node and then re-query to have the Regione    value. Just query on the upper node, i.e. `"Locali/{IDLocale}"`.

c/ Get all the Utenti and loop over them to find the ones with the region. Just build a query to get them.

```
exports.riAperturaLocale = functions.database.ref("Locali/{IDLocale}")
.onWrite(event => {
    const ID_Locale = event.params.IDLocale;
    const nascosto = event.data.val().Nascosto;

        if (!nascosto) {   // il locale sta aprendo

            const regione = event.data.val().Regione;

            const query = admin.database().ref("Utenti").orderByChild('Regione').equalTo(regione).once('value');

            return query.once('value').then(snap => {

                const notificationPromises = [];

                snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {

                    const userKey = childSnapshot.key;

                    const token = childSnapshot.val().token;

                    const img = Locale["ImmagineCopertina"];
                    // creo la notifica
                    const testo = Locale["Nome"] + " " + "di" + " " + Locale["Città"] + " ha aperto, "
                        + "entra a scoprire tutti gli Eventi!";

                    const titolo = 'Un nuovo Locale ha aperto!';                      

                    const payload = {
                                notification: {
                                    title: titolo,
                                    body: testo,
                                    sound: 'default',
                                    badge:"1"
                                },
                                data:{tipo: 'notifica',
                                    url: img,
                                    testo: testo,
                                    titolo: titolo,
                                    mittente:userKey
                                }
                            };

                    const p = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
                    notificationPromises.push(p);

                });

                return Promise.all(notificationPromises);

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                //other error treatment
            });

        } else {
            console.log("Il Locale sta chiudendo...:");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Videos from the Firebase team: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=1  and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc&index=3&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM

A last point: note that Cloud Functions have been updated to version 1.0.x and the syntax have changed. You may adapt your Function code accordingly to this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Question edited ;) Now the script works ok , but it's not sending the notifications as expected , maybe something wrong with the promises?

Comment: @GiulioSerra I have adapted the answer. Hoping it will help. You should return `Promise.all()` as explained in the third video I suggested. Also one "minor" point: most of the variables in this code can be declared as `const` and don't need to be declared with `let`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I sense some refactor coming ;)